# Getting [ui-leaflet] The marker definition is not valid. Received invalid data on the marker lng

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet

HELP i'm getting the following messages when I try to create marker fetched from my API

The marker definition is not valid.
Received invalid data on the marker layer.
The marker definition is not valid.
Received invalid data on the marker lat.
The marker definition is not valid.
Received invalid data on the marker lng.

```
var addressPointsToMarkers = function(points) {
            return points.map(function(ap) {
              return { 
                layer: 'bridges',
                lat: ap.latitude,
                lng: ap.longitude
              };
            });
      };
    $http({
            method : "GET",
            url : "some/url",
            headers : {
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
            }
    }).then( function(response) {
            $scope.markers = addressPointsToMarkers(response.data);
    });
```

i'm using angularJS 1.6.4 and leaflet 0.7.7

any idea how to solve this ?
thanks in advance

Comment: Do you use Leaflet 0.7.7 because of a specific reason? Else update to Version 1.7.1, it is much better supportet